# Coroutine (WaitForSeconds()) in "OnCollisionEnter()" gives compile error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a platformer game and I want to disable gravity of platforms after x seconds. But it gives a compile error that it can't be used since `void` isn't an interior interface type.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform(Clone)")
    {
        numberOfJumps = 2;
        Debug.Log("Platform hit");
    }

    // Make platforms fall
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    collision.rigidbody.useGravity = enabled;
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Your function has no return value therefore yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); is wrong.. (your english is fine)

Answer (score 8):

You can only yield in a `coroutine` function. You can't from a `void` function. Some Unity callback functions like the `Start` function can be made a `void` or coroutine function. Luckily, the `OnCollisionEnter` function is one of them so simply change the  `void` to `IEnumerator`. This will work without a need to manually start a new coroutine function. Unity will automatically call and start it as a coroutine when there is a collision.

```
private IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform(Clone)")
    {
        numberOfJumps = 2;
        Debug.Log("Platform hit");
    }

    //Maake platforms fall
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    collision.rigidbody.useGravity = enabled;
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should make a Coroutine and then call it inside of OnCollisionEnter. `Void` means that there is no return type for the method, which is why you got the compile errors.

```
IENumerator Fall(Rigidbody rigidbody)
{
    //Make platforms fall
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    rigidbody.useGravity = enabled;

}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform(Clone)")
    {
        numberOfJumps = 2;
        Debug.Log("Platform hit");
    }
    StartCoroutine(Fall(collision.rigidbody));
}
```